# Allow dired-do-copy and dired-do-rename to create new dir on the fly

Tags: emacs, elisp, file-management, dired

Does anyone have an emacs lisp hack that would allow the creation of a new directory on the fly during dired-do-copy or dired-do-rename?  I understand that it can be created prior to running one of these two commands.  Extra points for some type of "Are you sure..." prompt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It look like a case of applying an advice. The question being: what to
advice. Looking at the dired code, it seem that the correct target is 
`dired-mark-read-file-name` that is used to read the destination
file-name. This will work:

```
(defadvice dired-mark-read-file-name (after rv:dired-create-dir-when-needed (prompt dir op-symbol arg files &optional default) activate)
  (when (member op-symbol '(copy move))
    (let ((directory-name (if (< 1 (length files))
                              ad-return-value
                              (file-name-directory ad-return-value))))
      (when (and (not (file-directory-p directory-name))
                 (y-or-n-p (format "directory %s doesn't exist, create it?" directory-name)))
        (make-directory directory-name t)))))
```

Note that maybe the first `when` (`when (member op-symbol '(copy move))`) could be removed for this  to apply to more case of file creation in dired. But I'm not sure of when dired-mark-read-file-name is called, So I let this test there to reduce potential unwanted side-effect

Comment: Tried a test by evaluating the advice defun and using dired-do-copy "C"  It errored out with the following message. Copy `c:/Users/family/AppData/Roaming/temp.emacs' to `c:/Users/family/AppData/Roaming/temp110/temp.txt' failed: 
(file-error Copying file no such file or directory c:/Users/family/AppData/Roaming/temp.emacs c:/Users/family/AppData/Roaming/temp110/temp.txt)   
I am using emacs 24.2 under windows and dired+ which may redefine dired-do-copy.  Any suggestions?

Comment: It doesn't take care of this case. What my code is doing is creating the directories if either there are several file to copy or move, or there if you have given a directory name as answer to where to copy... I will look at a better solution If I've time...

Comment: Okay, I fixed it, It's even simpler like that.

Comment: Works well, tried several cases.  EMACS should work this way by default.  Thanks Mike